# How to add animation with CSS to svg

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I am currently working on an assignment from my IT teacher, where we are supposed to make a 4-way traffic light, and the car is supposed to stop at a red light. I am therefore trying to make the individual lights on the traffic light blink.

No keyframes animations work for this, and it is really frustrating.

I am trying to add code to this:

```
<circle cx="112" cy="82" r="13" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" 
fill="green" id="g"/>
<circle cx="112" cy="52" r="13" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" 
fill="yellow" id="b"/>
<circle cx="112" cy="22" r="13" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="red" 
id="r"/>

@keyframes red {
    from    {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: black;}
#r{
position: absolute;
animation-name: red;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

I am sorry if I seem very new to this, I am, and frankly, our teacher is really bad at his job, he can't, and won't explain stuff to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your keyframes animation from animating the `background-color` to animate the `fill` property:

```
@keyframes red {
    from    {fill: red;}
    to {fill: black;}
 }
```

Here's a working example:

```css
@keyframes red {
    from    {fill: red;}
    to {fill: black;}
 }
#r{
position: absolute;
animation-name: red;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg>
<circle cx="112" cy="82" r="13" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" 
fill="green" id="g"/>
<circle cx="112" cy="52" r="13" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" 
fill="yellow" id="b"/>
<circle cx="112" cy="22" r="13" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="red" 
id="r"/>
</svg>
```

It might seem odd, but with SVG `fill` is used instead of `background-color` for the background color.

Comment: Thanks, it works individually, but not with the rest of my code for some reason.